# Transaction Limit per block

Tags: transactions, gas-limit

I am developing a transaction analysis in a certain scenario on the Ethereum platform. Reading about, I understood that there is not a limit of transactions per block, but a limit of gas. Would anyone have a mathematical equation to calculate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gas limit changes every block.

For some easy ways to get the limit see: https://medium.com/@piyopiyo/how-to-get-ethereum-block-gas-limit-eba2c8f32ce

Comment: Can i use this command on Parity???

Comment: Yes! You could use the JSON rpc api in Parity https://wiki.parity.io/JSONRPC